# What substitution can we use instead of “positive” in "positive content"?

Tags: meaning

> In 1923, Hesse settled in Switzerland, where he had been living for the past ten years and remained until his death in 1962. There he adopted a stance of detachment from political struggles, which he presented as an example for Europe’s beleaguered intelligentsia. But what was the **positive** content of his vision, if any? Did it serve any impulse higher than an anxious need for peace and quiet? These are questions Decker does not answer.

Why is the word “positive” used here? Can’t we just say “content” instead of “positive content”?

Can you please paraphrase the sentence?

Answer (score 2):

I believe "positive" is very important here and you shouldn't omit it.

As I understand it, the fact that Hesse adopted a stance of detachment from political struggles is viewed (by the author of this article or book) as kind of negative. That's why the question `Did it serve any impulse higher than an anxious need for peace and quiet?` is asked. The author clearly sees the negative content of Hesse's vision, and he or she is wondering if there is any positive one. Apparently, need for peace and quiet is not considered positive enough.